# Flutter PageView align center when padEnds: false

Tags: flutter

How to center align PageView item when `padEnds: false`
[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Test',
        theme: ThemeData(),
        home: const Test(),
      );
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => PageView.builder(
        padEnds: false,
        controller: PageController(viewportFraction: .6),
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            color: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                .withOpacity(1),
            child: Center(child: Text('$index'))),
      );
}
```

Comment: what is `padEnds` ?

Comment: [padEnds](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillViewport/padEnds.html) Whether to add padding to both ends of the list.

Comment: So you want to center align the page view when user scrolls? That means only one item should be shown to the user ? @nazarpunk

Comment: When `padEnds: true`, pages are aligned in the center. I need center align when `padEnds: false`.

Comment: Can you add complete widget. I'm facing undefined 'padEnds'.also removing this working fine.

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/  `Based on Flutter 2.2.3`, but `padEnds: true` work in `Flutter version 2.5.0-6.0.pre.18`